# Proper way to store resources filenames in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, macos

what way would you recommend to store filenames of resources (e.g. images)
I use `#define` structures to store them as constants but I think it is quite ugly as those `#define` became visible outside class if you import its header.

As I understand there are few ways to store filenames:

- `#define` - I described cons above
- hardcoded filename in the code (like `[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]` I think this way make difficult to maintain nice code
- property file with dictionary (again, we need to store keys somewhere in the code)
  ....

I'm sure there is a nicer way to do that. Can you share what way do you use?

Actually I have same question for numeric `private` constants. e.g. button origin for custom view etc.. which shouldn't be visible outside class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it isn't always unacceptable to hard code the filename, if there's one single reference to the file, and the context of the reference (or attached comment) makes it obvious what the role of the filename is.

I would rarely recommend #define for a constant, because of type-checking issues. In Objective C a constant can be defined with

```
NSString * const kSomeImageFilename = @"myImage.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

In projects with large number of resources my team practices placing the resources in a plist.  Modifications of resource file names in this case only require an appropriate change within the plist.  The resource names are then retrieved by key from the plist.